# Cannot install Cedar Tail DRM in DKMS format on Ubuntu running on a netbook

Tags: 12.04, graphics, hardware, ubuntu-netbook

I have a netbook (Asus EeePC 1015CX) and recently I have installed Ubuntu 12.04LTS. All seems to run fine, however I have a problem with the graphics card.

1. When I turn on the computer the brightness is set to the lowest possible setting automatically, the buttons don't work (neither the option in the settings). The brightness is restored when I log off and back on.
2. Cedar Tail DRM driver which is shown in the Additional Drivers cannot be installed as it gives me an error.

Here is the shortened output from the file log from the error:

```
2013-05-26 09:57:30,350 WARNING: modinfo for module cedarview_gfx failed: ERROR: modinfo: could not find module cedarview_gfx

2013-05-26 09:57:30,352 DEBUG: got handler kmod:cedarview_gfx([KernelModuleHandler, nonfree, disabled] Cedar Trail drm driver in DKMS format.)
2013-05-26 09:57:30,352 DEBUG: querying driver db <jockey.detection.LocalKernelModulesDriverDB instance at 0x904da0c> about HardwareID('modalias', 'pci:v00008086d000027D8sv00001043sd00008437bc04sc03i00')
2013-05-26 09:57:30,380 DEBUG: searching handler for driver ID {'driver_type': 'kernel_module', 'kernel_module': 'snd_hda_intel'}
2013-05-26 09:57:30,381 DEBUG: no corresponding handler available for {'driver_type': 'kernel_module', 'kernel_module': 'snd_hda_intel', 'jockey_handler': 'KernelModuleHandler'}
2013-05-26 09:57:30,381 DEBUG: searching handler for driver ID {'driver_type': 'kernel_module', 'kernel_module': 'snd_hda_intel'}
2013-05-26 09:57:30,382 DEBUG: no corresponding handler available for {'driver_type': 'kernel_module', 'kernel_module': 'snd_hda_intel', 'jockey_handler': 'KernelModuleHandler'}
2013-05-26 09:57:30,383 DEBUG: querying driver db <jockey.detection.LocalKernelModulesDriverDB instance at 0x904da0c> about HardwareID('modalias', 'acpi:PNP0C01:')
2013-05-26 09:57:30,383 DEBUG: querying driver db <jockey.detection.LocalKernelModulesDriverDB instance at 0x904da0c> about HardwareID('modalias', 'pci:v00008086d000027C1sv00001043sd000083ADbc01sc06i01')
2013-05-26 09:57:30,409 DEBUG: searching handler for driver ID {'driver_type': 'kernel_module', 'kernel_module': 'ahci'}
2013-05-26 09:57:30,410 DEBUG: no corresponding handler available for {'driver_type': 'kernel_module', 'kernel_module': 'ahci', 'jockey_handler': 'KernelModuleHandler'}
2013-05-26 09:57:30,411 DEBUG: searching handler for driver ID {'driver_type': 'kernel_module', 'kernel_module': 'ahci'}
2013-05-26 09:57:30,411 DEBUG: no corresponding handler available for {'driver_type': 'kernel_module', 'kernel_module': 'ahci', 'jockey_handler': 'KernelModuleHandler'}
2013-05-26 09:57:30,412 DEBUG: querying driver db <jockey.detection.LocalKernelModulesDriverDB instance at 0x904da0c> about HardwareID('modalias', 'acpi:INT0800:')
2013-05-26 09:57:30,412 DEBUG: querying driver db <jockey.detection.LocalKernelModulesDriverDB instance at 0x904da0c> about HardwareID('modalias', 'pci:v00008086d000027CCsv00001043sd000083ADbc0Csc03i20')
2013-05-26 09:57:30,439 DEBUG: querying driver db <jockey.detection.LocalKernelModulesDriverDB instance at 0x904da0c> about HardwareID('modalias', 'acpi:PNP0303:PNP030B:')
2013-05-26 09:57:30,439 DEBUG: querying driver db <jockey.detection.LocalKernelModulesDriverDB instance at 0x904da0c> about HardwareID('modalias', 'input:b0011v0001p0001eAB41-e0,1,4,11,14,k71,72,73,74,75,76,77,79,7A,7B,7C,7D,7E,7F,80,8C,8E,8F,9B,9C,9D,9E,9F,A3,A4,A5,A6,AC,AD,B7,B8,B9,D9,E2,ram4,l0,1,2,sfw')
2013-05-26 09:57:30,441 DEBUG: searching handler for driver ID {'driver_type': 'kernel_module', 'kernel_module': 'evbug'}
2013-05-26 09:57:30,441 DEBUG: no corresponding handler available for {'driver_type': 'kernel_module', 'kernel_module': 'evbug', 'jockey_handler': 'KernelModuleHandler'}
2013-05-26 09:57:30,442 DEBUG: searching handler for driver ID {'driver_type': 'kernel_module', 'kernel_module': 'mac_hid'}
2013-05-26 09:57:30,443 DEBUG: no corresponding handler available for {'driver_type': 'kernel_module', 'kernel_module': 'mac_hid', 'jockey_handler': 'KernelModuleHandler'}
2013-05-26 09:57:30,443 DEBUG: querying driver db <jockey.detection.LocalKernelModulesDriverDB instance at 0x904da0c> about HardwareID('modalias', 'input:b0019v0000p0001e0000-e0,1,k74,ramlsfw')
2013-05-26 09:57:30,444 DEBUG: searching handler for driver ID {'driver_type': 'kernel_module', 'kernel_module': 'evbug'}
2013-05-26 09:57:30,445 DEBUG: no corresponding handler available for {'driver_type': 'kernel_module', 'kernel_module': 'evbug', 'jockey_handler': 'KernelModuleHandler'}
2013-05-26 09:57:30,445 DEBUG: searching handler for driver ID {'driver_type': 'kernel_module', 'kernel_module': 'mac_hid'}
2013-05-26 09:57:30,446 DEBUG: no corresponding handler available for {'driver_type': 'kernel_module', 'kernel_module': 'mac_hid', 'jockey_handler': 'KernelModuleHandler'}
2013-05-26 09:57:30,446 DEBUG: querying driver db <jockey.detection.LocalKernelModulesDriverDB instance at 0x904da0c> about HardwareID('modalias', 'input:b0003v13D3p5711e1204-e0,1,kD4,ramlsfw')
2013-05-26 09:57:30,447 DEBUG: searching handler for driver ID {'driver_type': 'kernel_module', 'kernel_module': 'evbug'}
2013-05-26 09:57:30,448 DEBUG: no corresponding handler available for {'driver_type': 'kernel_module', 'kernel_module': 'evbug', 'jockey_handler': 'KernelModuleHandler'}
2013-05-26 09:57:30,448 DEBUG: searching handler for driver ID {'driver_type': 'kernel_module', 'kernel_module': 'mac_hid'}
2013-05-26 09:57:30,449 DEBUG: no corresponding handler available for {'driver_type': 'kernel_module', 'kernel_module': 'mac_hid', 'jockey_handler': 'KernelModuleHandler'}
2013-05-26 09:57:30,450 DEBUG: querying driver db <jockey.detection.LocalKernelModulesDriverDB instance at 0x904da0c> about HardwareID('modalias', 'acpi:LNXSYBUS:')
2013-05-26 09:57:30,450 DEBUG: querying driver db <jockey.detection.LocalKernelModulesDriverDB instance at 0x904da0c> about HardwareID('modalias', 'dmi:bvnAmericanMegatrendsInc.:bvr1015CX.0501:bd02/07/2012:svnASUSTeKCOMPUTERINC.:pn1015CX:pvrx.x:rvnASUSTeKCOMPUTERINC.:rn1015CX:rvrx.xx:cvnASUSTeKCOMPUTERINC.:ct10:cvrx.x:')
2013-05-26 09:57:30,528 DEBUG: querying driver db <jockey.detection.LocalKernelModulesDriverDB instance at 0x904da0c> about HardwareID('modalias', 'pci:v00001969d00002062sv00001043sd00008468bc02sc00i00')
2013-05-26 09:57:30,559 DEBUG: searching handler for driver ID {'driver_type': 'kernel_module', 'kernel_module': 'atl1c'}
2013-05-26 09:57:30,559 DEBUG: no corresponding handler available for {'driver_type': 'kernel_module', 'kernel_module': 'atl1c', 'jockey_handler': 'KernelModuleHandler'}
2013-05-26 09:57:30,560 DEBUG: querying driver db <jockey.detection.LocalKernelModulesDriverDB instance at 0x904da0c> about HardwareID('modalias', 'input:b0011v0002p0007e01B1-e0,1,3,k110,111,145,14A,14D,14E,ra0,1,18,1C,2F,35,36,39,mlsfw')
2013-05-26 09:57:30,561 DEBUG: searching handler for driver ID {'driver_type': 'kernel_module', 'kernel_module': 'evbug'}
2013-05-26 09:57:30,562 DEBUG: no corresponding handler available for {'driver_type': 'kernel_module', 'kernel_module': 'evbug', 'jockey_handler': 'KernelModuleHandler'}
2013-05-26 09:57:30,562 DEBUG: searching handler for driver ID {'driver_type': 'kernel_module', 'kernel_module': 'joydev'}
2013-05-26 09:57:30,563 DEBUG: no corresponding handler available for {'driver_type': 'kernel_module', 'kernel_module': 'joydev', 'jockey_handler': 'KernelModuleHandler'}
2013-05-26 09:57:30,563 DEBUG: searching handler for driver ID {'driver_type': 'kernel_module', 'kernel_module': 'joydev'}
2013-05-26 09:57:30,564 DEBUG: no corresponding handler available for {'driver_type': 'kernel_module', 'kernel_module': 'joydev', 'jockey_handler': 'KernelModuleHandler'}
2013-05-26 09:57:30,565 DEBUG: searching handler for driver ID {'driver_type': 'kernel_module', 'kernel_module': 'joydev'}
2013-05-26 09:57:30,566 DEBUG: no corresponding handler available for {'driver_type': 'kernel_module', 'kernel_module': 'joydev', 'jockey_handler': 'KernelModuleHandler'}
2013-05-26 09:57:30,566 DEBUG: searching handler for driver ID {'driver_type': 'kernel_module', 'kernel_module': 'mac_hid'}
2013-05-26 09:57:30,567 DEBUG: no corresponding handler available for {'driver_type': 'kernel_module', 'kernel_module': 'mac_hid', 'jockey_handler': 'KernelModuleHandler'}
2013-05-26 09:57:30,567 DEBUG: querying driver db <jockey.detection.LocalKernelModulesDriverDB instance at 0x904da0c> about HardwareID('modalias', 'usb:v13D3p5711d1204dcEFdsc02dp01ic0Eisc02ip00')
2013-05-26 09:57:30,697 DEBUG: querying driver db <jockey.detection.LocalKernelModulesDriverDB instance at 0x904da0c> about HardwareID('modalias', 'usb:v13D3p5711d1204dcEFdsc02dp01ic0Eisc01ip00')
2013-05-26 09:57:30,700 DEBUG: searching handler for driver ID {'driver_type': 'kernel_module', 'kernel_module': 'uvcvideo'}
2013-05-26 09:57:30,701 DEBUG: no corresponding handler available for {'driver_type': 'kernel_module', 'kernel_module': 'uvcvideo', 'jockey_handler': 'KernelModuleHandler'}
2013-05-26 09:57:30,702 DEBUG: querying driver db <jockey.detection.LocalKernelModulesDriverDB instance at 0x904da0c> about HardwareID('modalias', 'pci:v00008086d000027CAsv00001043sd000083ADbc0Csc03i00')
2013-05-26 09:57:30,726 DEBUG: querying driver db <jockey.detection.LocalKernelModulesDriverDB instance at 0x904da0c> about HardwareID('modalias', 'pci:v00008086d000027CBsv00001043sd000083ADbc0Csc03i00')
2013-05-26 09:57:30,753 DEBUG: querying driver db <jockey.detection.LocalKernelModulesDriverDB instance at 0x904da0c> about HardwareID('modalias', 'pci:v00008086d00000BF1sv00001043sd000084A9bc06sc00i00')
2013-05-26 09:57:30,779 DEBUG: querying driver db <jockey.detection.LocalKernelModulesDriverDB instance at 0x904da0c> about HardwareID('modalias', 'acpi:ETD0101:PNP0F13:')
2013-05-26 09:57:30,779 DEBUG: querying driver db <jockey.detection.LocalKernelModulesDriverDB instance at 0x904da0c> about HardwareID('modalias', 'platform:Fixed MDIO bus')
2013-05-26 09:57:30,783 DEBUG: querying driver db <jockey.detection.LocalKernelModulesDriverDB instance at 0x904da0c> about HardwareID('modalias', 'pci:v0000168Cd0000002Bsv00001A3Bsd00001089bc02sc80i00')
2013-05-26 09:57:30,847 DEBUG: searching handler for driver ID {'driver_type': 'kernel_module', 'kernel_module': 'ath9k'}
2013-05-26 09:57:30,847 DEBUG: no corresponding handler available for {'driver_type': 'kernel_module', 'kernel_module': 'ath9k', 'jockey_handler': 'KernelModuleHandler'}
2013-05-26 09:57:30,848 DEBUG: querying driver db <jockey.detection.LocalKernelModulesDriverDB instance at 0x904da0c> about HardwareID('modalias', 'wmi:05901221-D566-11D1-B2F0-00A0C9062910')
2013-05-26 09:57:30,849 DEBUG: querying driver db <jockey.detection.LocalKernelModulesDriverDB instance at 0x904da0c> about HardwareID('modalias', 'platform:pcspkr')
2013-05-26 09:57:30,852 DEBUG: searching handler for driver ID {'driver_type': 'kernel_module', 'kernel_module': 'pcspkr'}
2013-05-26 09:57:30,853 DEBUG: no corresponding handler available for {'driver_type': 'kernel_module', 'kernel_module': 'pcspkr', 'jockey_handler': 'KernelModuleHandler'}
2013-05-26 09:57:30,854 DEBUG: searching handler for driver ID {'driver_type': 'kernel_module', 'kernel_module': 'snd_pcsp'}
2013-05-26 09:57:30,854 DEBUG: no corresponding handler available for {'driver_type': 'kernel_module', 'kernel_module': 'snd_pcsp', 'jockey_handler': 'KernelModuleHandler'}
2013-05-26 09:57:30,855 DEBUG: querying driver db <jockey.detection.LocalKernelModulesDriverDB instance at 0x904da0c> about HardwareID('modalias', 'platform:coretemp')
2013-05-26 09:57:30,858 DEBUG: querying driver db <jockey.detection.LocalKernelModulesDriverDB instance at 0x904da0c> about HardwareID('modalias', 'x86cpu:vendor:0000:family:0006:model:0036:feature:,0000,0001,0002,0003,0004,0005,0006,0007,0008,0009,000B,000C,000D,000E,000F,0010,0011,0013,0015,0016,0017,0018,0019,001A,001B,001C,001D,001F,0034,0066,0068,006B,006C,006D,0072,0078,007C,0080,0082,0083,0084,0087,0088,0089,008E,008F,0096,00C0,00E1,00E7')
2013-05-26 09:57:30,893 DEBUG: searching handler for driver ID {'driver_type': 'kernel_module', 'kernel_module': 'microcode'}
2013-05-26 09:57:30,893 DEBUG: no corresponding handler available for {'driver_type': 'kernel_module', 'kernel_module': 'microcode', 'jockey_handler': 'KernelModuleHandler'}
2013-05-26 09:57:30,894 DEBUG: searching handler for driver ID {'driver_type': 'kernel_module', 'kernel_module': 'coretemp'}
2013-05-26 09:57:30,895 DEBUG: no corresponding handler available for {'driver_type': 'kernel_module', 'kernel_module': 'coretemp', 'jockey_handler': 'KernelModuleHandler'}
2013-05-26 09:57:30,895 DEBUG: querying driver db <jockey.detection.LocalKernelModulesDriverDB instance at 0x904da0c> about HardwareID('modalias', 'serio:ty01pr00id00ex00')
2013-05-26 09:57:30,943 DEBUG: searching handler for driver ID {'driver_type': 'kernel_module', 'kernel_module': 'serio_raw'}
2013-05-26 09:57:30,944 DEBUG: no corresponding handler available for {'driver_type': 'kernel_module', 'kernel_module': 'serio_raw', 'jockey_handler': 'KernelModuleHandler'}
2013-05-26 09:57:30,944 DEBUG: searching handler for driver ID {'driver_type': 'kernel_module', 'kernel_module': 'psmouse'}
2013-05-26 09:57:30,945 DEBUG: no corresponding handler available for {'driver_type': 'kernel_module', 'kernel_module': 'psmouse', 'jockey_handler': 'KernelModuleHandler'}
2013-05-26 09:57:30,946 DEBUG: querying driver db <jockey.detection.LocalKernelModulesDriverDB instance at 0x904da0c> about HardwareID('modalias', 'input:b0019v0000p0003e0000-e0,1,k8E,ramlsfw')
2013-05-26 09:57:30,947 DEBUG: searching handler for driver ID {'driver_type': 'kernel_module', 'kernel_module': 'evbug'}
2013-05-26 09:57:30,948 DEBUG: no corresponding handler available for {'driver_type': 'kernel_module', 'kernel_module': 'evbug', 'jockey_handler': 'KernelModuleHandler'}
2013-05-26 09:57:30,948 DEBUG: searching handler for driver ID {'driver_type': 'kernel_module', 'kernel_module': 'mac_hid'}
2013-05-26 09:57:30,949 DEBUG: no corresponding handler available for {'driver_type': 'kernel_module', 'kernel_module': 'mac_hid', 'jockey_handler': 'KernelModuleHandler'}
2013-05-26 09:57:30,950 DEBUG: querying driver db <jockey.detection.LocalKernelModulesDriverDB instance at 0x904da0c> about HardwareID('modalias', 'input:b0000v0000p0000e0000-e0,5,kramlsfw6,8,')
2013-05-26 09:57:30,950 DEBUG: searching handler for driver ID {'driver_type': 'kernel_module', 'kernel_module': 'evbug'}
2013-05-26 09:57:30,951 DEBUG: no corresponding handler available for {'driver_type': 'kernel_module', 'kernel_module': 'evbug', 'jockey_handler': 'KernelModuleHandler'}
2013-05-26 09:57:30,952 DEBUG: querying driver db <jockey.detection.LocalKernelModulesDriverDB instance at 0x904da0c> about HardwareID('modalias', 'input:b0019v0000p0005e0000-e0,5,kramlsfw0,')
2013-05-26 09:57:30,952 DEBUG: searching handler for driver ID {'driver_type': 'kernel_module', 'kernel_module': 'evbug'}
2013-05-26 09:57:30,953 DEBUG: no corresponding handler available for {'driver_type': 'kernel_module', 'kernel_module': 'evbug', 'jockey_handler': 'KernelModuleHandler'}
2013-05-26 09:57:30,954 DEBUG: querying driver db <jockey.detection.LocalKernelModulesDriverDB instance at 0x904da0c> about HardwareID('modalias', 'wmi:466747A0-70EC-11DE-8A39-0800200C9A66')
2013-05-26 09:57:30,954 DEBUG: querying driver db <jockey.detection.OpenPrintingDriverDB instance at 0x92e68cc> about HardwareID('modalias', 'pci:v00008086d000027C9sv00001043sd000083ADbc0Csc03i00')
2013-05-26 09:57:30,955 DEBUG: querying driver db <jockey.detection.OpenPrintingDriverDB instance at 0x92e68cc> about HardwareID('modalias', 'input:b0019v0000p0000e0000-e0,1,4,14,k71,72,73,8B,94,98,AB,AC,B8,B9,BF,D4,E3,EE,F0,F4,215,216,217,218,219,21A,ram4,lsfw')
2013-05-26 09:57:30,955 DEBUG: querying driver db <jockey.detection.OpenPrintingDriverDB instance at 0x92e68cc> about HardwareID('modalias', 'acpi:PNP0C02:')
2013-05-26 09:57:30,956 DEBUG: querying driver db <jockey.detection.OpenPrintingDriverDB instance at 0x92e68cc> about HardwareID('modalias', 'pci:v00008086d000027DAsv00001043sd000083ADbc0Csc05i00')
2013-05-26 09:57:30,956 DEBUG: querying driver db <jockey.detection.OpenPrintingDriverDB instance at 0x92e68cc> about HardwareID('modalias', 'pci:v00008086d000027BCsv00001043sd000083ADbc06sc01i00')
2013-05-26 09:57:30,957 DEBUG: querying driver db <jockey.detection.OpenPrintingDriverDB instance at 0x92e68cc> about HardwareID('modalias', 'platform:regulatory')
2013-05-26 09:57:30,957 DEBUG: querying driver db <jockey.detection.OpenPrintingDriverDB instance at 0x92e68cc> about HardwareID('modalias', 'input:b0019v0000p0006e0000-e0,1,kE0,E1,E3,F1,F2,F3,F4,F5,ramlsfw')
2013-05-26 09:57:30,958 DEBUG: querying driver db <jockey.detection.OpenPrintingDriverDB instance at 0x92e68cc> about HardwareID('modalias', 'usb:v1D6Bp0001d0305dc09dsc00dp00ic09isc00ip00')
2013-05-26 09:57:30,958 DEBUG: querying driver db <jockey.detection.OpenPrintingDriverDB instance at 0x92e68cc> about HardwareID('modalias', 'usb:v1D6Bp0002d0305dc09dsc00dp00ic09isc00ip00')
2013-05-26 09:57:30,959 DEBUG: querying driver db <jockey.detection.OpenPrintingDriverDB instance at 0x92e68cc> about HardwareID('modalias', 'input:b0000v0000p0000e0000-e0,5,kramlsfw2,')
2013-05-26 09:57:30,959 DEBUG: querying driver db <jockey.detection.OpenPrintingDriverDB instance at 0x92e68cc> about HardwareID('modalias', 'platform:microcode')
2013-05-26 09:57:30,959 DEBUG: querying driver db <jockey.detection.OpenPrintingDriverDB instance at 0x92e68cc> about HardwareID('modalias', 'acpi:LNXSYSTM:')
2013-05-26 09:57:30,960 DEBUG: querying driver db <jockey.detection.OpenPrintingDriverDB instance at 0x92e68cc> about HardwareID('modalias', 'platform:eisa')
2013-05-26 09:57:30,961 DEBUG: querying driver db <jockey.detection.OpenPrintingDriverDB instance at 0x92e68cc> about HardwareID('modalias', 'platform:eeepc-wmi')
2013-05-26 09:57:30,961 DEBUG: querying driver db <jockey.detection.OpenPrintingDriverDB instance at 0x92e68cc> about HardwareID('modalias', 'wmi:ABBC0F72-8EA1-11D1-00A0-C90629100000')
2013-05-26 09:57:30,962 DEBUG: querying driver db <jockey.detection.OpenPrintingDriverDB instance at 0x92e68cc> about HardwareID('modalias', 'pci:v00008086d00002448sv00001043sd000083ADbc06sc04i01')
2013-05-26 09:57:30,962 DEBUG: querying driver db <jockey.detection.OpenPrintingDriverDB instance at 0x92e68cc> about HardwareID('modalias', 'wmi:97845ED0-4E6D-11DE-8A39-0800200C9A66')
2013-05-26 09:57:30,963 DEBUG: querying driver db <jockey.detection.OpenPrintingDriverDB instance at 0x92e68cc> about HardwareID('modalias', 'pci:v00008086d000027C8sv00001043sd000083ADbc0Csc03i00')
2013-05-26 09:57:30,964 DEBUG: querying driver db <jockey.detection.OpenPrintingDriverDB instance at 0x92e68cc> about HardwareID('modalias', 'pci:v00008086d00000BE1sv00001043sd000084A9bc03sc00i00')
2013-05-26 09:57:30,964 DEBUG: querying driver db <jockey.detection.OpenPrintingDriverDB instance at 0x92e68cc> about HardwareID('modalias', 'pci:v00008086d000027D8sv00001043sd00008437bc04sc03i00')
2013-05-26 09:57:30,965 DEBUG: querying driver db <jockey.detection.OpenPrintingDriverDB instance at 0x92e68cc> about HardwareID('modalias', 'acpi:PNP0C01:')
2013-05-26 09:57:30,965 DEBUG: querying driver db <jockey.detection.OpenPrintingDriverDB instance at 0x92e68cc> about HardwareID('modalias', 'pci:v00008086d000027C1sv00001043sd000083ADbc01sc06i01')
2013-05-26 09:57:30,966 DEBUG: querying driver db <jockey.detection.OpenPrintingDriverDB instance at 0x92e68cc> about HardwareID('modalias', 'acpi:INT0800:')
2013-05-26 09:57:30,966 DEBUG: querying driver db <jockey.detection.OpenPrintingDriverDB instance at 0x92e68cc> about HardwareID('modalias', 'pci:v00008086d000027CCsv00001043sd000083ADbc0Csc03i20')
2013-05-26 09:57:30,967 DEBUG: querying driver db <jockey.detection.OpenPrintingDriverDB instance at 0x92e68cc> about HardwareID('modalias', 'acpi:PNP0303:PNP030B:')
2013-05-26 09:57:30,967 DEBUG: querying driver db <jockey.detection.OpenPrintingDriverDB instance at 0x92e68cc> about HardwareID('modalias', 'input:b0011v0001p0001eAB41-e0,1,4,11,14,k71,72,73,74,75,76,77,79,7A,7B,7C,7D,7E,7F,80,8C,8E,8F,9B,9C,9D,9E,9F,A3,A4,A5,A6,AC,AD,B7,B8,B9,D9,E2,ram4,l0,1,2,sfw')
2013-05-26 09:57:30,968 DEBUG: querying driver db <jockey.detection.OpenPrintingDriverDB instance at 0x92e68cc> about HardwareID('modalias', 'input:b0019v0000p0001e0000-e0,1,k74,ramlsfw')
2013-05-26 09:57:30,968 DEBUG: querying driver db <jockey.detection.OpenPrintingDriverDB instance at 0x92e68cc> about HardwareID('modalias', 'input:b0003v13D3p5711e1204-e0,1,kD4,ramlsfw')
2013-05-26 09:57:30,969 DEBUG: querying driver db <jockey.detection.OpenPrintingDriverDB instance at 0x92e68cc> about HardwareID('modalias', 'acpi:LNXSYBUS:')
2013-05-26 09:57:30,969 DEBUG: querying driver db <jockey.detection.OpenPrintingDriverDB instance at 0x92e68cc> about HardwareID('modalias', 'dmi:bvnAmericanMegatrendsInc.:bvr1015CX.0501:bd02/07/2012:svnASUSTeKCOMPUTERINC.:pn1015CX:pvrx.x:rvnASUSTeKCOMPUTERINC.:rn1015CX:rvrx.xx:cvnASUSTeKCOMPUTERINC.:ct10:cvrx.x:')
2013-05-26 09:57:30,970 DEBUG: querying driver db <jockey.detection.OpenPrintingDriverDB instance at 0x92e68cc> about HardwareID('modalias', 'pci:v00001969d00002062sv00001043sd00008468bc02sc00i00')
2013-05-26 09:57:30,970 DEBUG: querying driver db <jockey.detection.OpenPrintingDriverDB instance at 0x92e68cc> about HardwareID('modalias', 'input:b0011v0002p0007e01B1-e0,1,3,k110,111,145,14A,14D,14E,ra0,1,18,1C,2F,35,36,39,mlsfw')
2013-05-26 09:57:30,971 DEBUG: querying driver db <jockey.detection.OpenPrintingDriverDB instance at 0x92e68cc> about HardwareID('modalias', 'usb:v13D3p5711d1204dcEFdsc02dp01ic0Eisc02ip00')
2013-05-26 09:57:30,971 DEBUG: querying driver db <jockey.detection.OpenPrintingDriverDB instance at 0x92e68cc> about HardwareID('modalias', 'usb:v13D3p5711d1204dcEFdsc02dp01ic0Eisc01ip00')
2013-05-26 09:57:30,972 DEBUG: querying driver db <jockey.detection.OpenPrintingDriverDB instance at 0x92e68cc> about HardwareID('modalias', 'pci:v00008086d000027CAsv00001043sd000083ADbc0Csc03i00')
2013-05-26 09:57:30,972 DEBUG: querying driver db <jockey.detection.OpenPrintingDriverDB instance at 0x92e68cc> about HardwareID('modalias', 'pci:v00008086d000027CBsv00001043sd000083ADbc0Csc03i00')
2013-05-26 09:57:30,973 DEBUG: querying driver db <jockey.detection.OpenPrintingDriverDB instance at 0x92e68cc> about HardwareID('modalias', 'pci:v00008086d00000BF1sv00001043sd000084A9bc06sc00i00')
2013-05-26 09:57:30,973 DEBUG: querying driver db <jockey.detection.OpenPrintingDriverDB instance at 0x92e68cc> about HardwareID('modalias', 'acpi:ETD0101:PNP0F13:')
2013-05-26 09:57:30,974 DEBUG: querying driver db <jockey.detection.OpenPrintingDriverDB instance at 0x92e68cc> about HardwareID('modalias', 'platform:Fixed MDIO bus')
2013-05-26 09:57:30,974 DEBUG: querying driver db <jockey.detection.OpenPrintingDriverDB instance at 0x92e68cc> about HardwareID('modalias', 'pci:v0000168Cd0000002Bsv00001A3Bsd00001089bc02sc80i00')
2013-05-26 09:57:30,974 DEBUG: querying driver db <jockey.detection.OpenPrintingDriverDB instance at 0x92e68cc> about HardwareID('modalias', 'wmi:05901221-D566-11D1-B2F0-00A0C9062910')
2013-05-26 09:57:30,975 DEBUG: querying driver db <jockey.detection.OpenPrintingDriverDB instance at 0x92e68cc> about HardwareID('modalias', 'platform:pcspkr')
2013-05-26 09:57:30,975 DEBUG: querying driver db <jockey.detection.OpenPrintingDriverDB instance at 0x92e68cc> about HardwareID('modalias', 'platform:coretemp')
2013-05-26 09:57:30,976 DEBUG: querying driver db <jockey.detection.OpenPrintingDriverDB instance at 0x92e68cc> about HardwareID('modalias', 'x86cpu:vendor:0000:family:0006:model:0036:feature:,0000,0001,0002,0003,0004,0005,0006,0007,0008,0009,000B,000C,000D,000E,000F,0010,0011,0013,0015,0016,0017,0018,0019,001A,001B,001C,001D,001F,0034,0066,0068,006B,006C,006D,0072,0078,007C,0080,0082,0083,0084,0087,0088,0089,008E,008F,0096,00C0,00E1,00E7')
2013-05-26 09:57:30,976 DEBUG: querying driver db <jockey.detection.OpenPrintingDriverDB instance at 0x92e68cc> about HardwareID('modalias', 'serio:ty01pr00id00ex00')
2013-05-26 09:57:30,977 DEBUG: querying driver db <jockey.detection.OpenPrintingDriverDB instance at 0x92e68cc> about HardwareID('modalias', 'input:b0019v0000p0003e0000-e0,1,k8E,ramlsfw')
2013-05-26 09:57:30,977 DEBUG: querying driver db <jockey.detection.OpenPrintingDriverDB instance at 0x92e68cc> about HardwareID('modalias', 'input:b0000v0000p0000e0000-e0,5,kramlsfw6,8,')
2013-05-26 09:57:30,978 DEBUG: querying driver db <jockey.detection.OpenPrintingDriverDB instance at 0x92e68cc> about HardwareID('modalias', 'input:b0019v0000p0005e0000-e0,5,kramlsfw0,')
2013-05-26 09:57:30,978 DEBUG: querying driver db <jockey.detection.OpenPrintingDriverDB instance at 0x92e68cc> about HardwareID('modalias', 'wmi:466747A0-70EC-11DE-8A39-0800200C9A66')
2013-05-26 09:57:57,347 WARNING: modinfo for module cedarview_gfx failed: ERROR: modinfo: could not find module cedarview_gfx

2013-05-26 09:57:57,348 WARNING: /sys/module/cedarview_gfx/drivers does not exist, cannot rebind cedarview_gfx driver
```

How can I fix this? I know that the netbook has integrated graphic card.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try running the updates first (and reboot).

I had the same problem, dark screen and error trying to install cedarview driver, but this happened only at first boot, then I ran the update and after reboot everything is fine.

I still cannot install cedarview driver, but light is ok.

Answer (score 1):

You may need to change your kernel to 32-bit generic (WITHOUT pae). See http://ef.gy/ubuntu-cedarview-drivers

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! It is advisable to also post the commands from the link you provided into your answer, so that other people can know how to do your suggested solution, if the link ever dies.

Answer (score 0):

This is a recognized bug: [Bug #1132584](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/cedarview-drm-drivers/+bug/1132584)

The solution is too simple:

> If Cedarview owners (Intel Atom D2500/D2700/N2600/N2800) want to use
>   this module, they are encouraged to do [a clean install of Ubuntu
>   12.04.1](http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/releases/12.04.1/). Once 12.04.1 is installed, the users should not install newer lts-kernel or
>   lts-xserver packages, as they need to run kernel 3.2.x for the module
>   to work correctly.

I hope this will be of your interest.